# Why must the keys to asymmetric encryption have to be as much longer such as RSA than typical symmetrical encryption algorithms, such as AES?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa

I'm reading that it is because RSA has to do with math (prime numbers) while Symmetric key encryption is about taking blocks of data and modifying the blocks with replacements and remappings, but I still don't understand why Asymmetric encryption has to have longer keys because of that, or if that's even why?

Comment: Key sizes are chosen so that the **best available** attack is at least as hard as a certain predefined hardness. For symmetric algorithms like 128-bit AES, that "hardness" is about 2**128 steps (1 step = 1 AES encryption operation). Asymmetric algorithms are based on number-theoretic problems and their best available attacks tend to be very complicated, mathy algorithms, but the bottom line is that the equivalent RSA key size to make RSA as hard as 128-bit AES is about 3000 bits. However, to make RSA about as hard as 256-bit AES it needs a modulus size of around 15000 bits.

Comment: This question is probably better asked at the security or crypto stackexchange site, and I would guess it's already been asked and answered there.

Comment: But why does it have to be longer than symmetric encryption algorithms? I know there is a correlation between time spent encrypting and security and u have to find the sweet spot, but why do keys to public key algorithms have to be longer than the keys used in symmetric algorithms?

Comment: Taking RSA for example, I could break 128-bit RSA in a few minutes on my computer. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Is it because you'd be able to factor that many prime numbers in a short amount of time? I mean why does that neccessarily make it need a longer key than DES does which is a symmetrick block cipher? Is the because it's easier to break public key cryptography because it's math stuff? Primes and modulos, exponents etc?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com)

Comment: The larger keys are necessary because they are required for RSA. If you use Elliptic Curves Crypto (also asymmetric) instead you have smaller keys.

Answer (score 0):

For symmetric ciphers, the cipher strength depends on the key length assuming the cipher is not broken.

Asymmetric encryption is based on a trapdoor function (not necessarily prime numbers, there are others as well, such as elliptic curves or lattices). It should be one way function (for encryption) with very difficult computation of its inverse (decryption) without some kind of secret. So the strength of the asymmetric cipher depends on key length and as well on how difficult is to compute the function inverse with the specific key length

Example: breaking a 128 bit symmetric key would mean testing 2^128 numbers. Solving discrete logarithm problem (inverse of RSA) for 128 bit key will take much less time (we need to solve a math problem, not find a random key), so much longer key is needed to make up the same level of security